# Unable to render children in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am calling a React component with children like so:

```
<SignUpFormWizard
          initialValues={initialFormValues}
          onSubmit={(values, props) => this._submit(values, props)}
        >
    <Text style={styles.lightText}>Wizard.</Text>
</SignUpFormWizard>
```

And my `SignUpFormWizard` component is like so:

```
export default class SignUpFormWizard extends React.Component {
    // static Page = ({ children }) => children;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // console.log(props);
        this.state = { page: 0, values: props.initialValues };
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        console.log("Render");
        console.log(children);
        return <React.Fragment />;
    }
}
```

However, whenever I execute this, the system just freezes for a while and ends with the message `There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment.`

When I try to render `{ children }`, I get an error message saying `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}).`.

I need to know how to go about it. Basically, this is just skeleton code for what I'm trying to achieve, i.e., render children components in a React component.

Comment: Show us how exactly you are trying to render `{this.props.children}`

Comment: Rendering it using `return { this.props.children };` in the `render()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to render the `children` and that's it, then you can update `SignUpFormWizard` to look something like this:

```
const SignUpFormWizard = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

export default SignUpFormWizard;
```

Since you're calling the `SignUpFormWizard` component like:

```
<SignUpFormWizard
  initialValues={initialFormValues}
  onSubmit={(values, props) => this._submit(values, props)}
>
  <Text style={styles.lightText}>Wizard.</Text>
</SignUpFormWizard>
```

I can guess you need to read `initialValues` and `onSubmit` props something like:

```
const SignUpFormWizard = ({ children, initialValues, onSubmit }) => 
  <>
    {initialValues.map(value => (<div>{value}</div>))}
    {children}
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>Sign Up</button>
  </>;

export default SignUpFormWizard;
```

Comment: I had to use a class (state requirements, etc.) but I figured out a small mistake on my part. I have accepted your answer though. Thanks for the help 

Comment: @GauravWadhwani ok, cool! Glad you've solved your question 